# Exception Code: c0000005 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, exception, visual-studio-2013, openfiledialog

I made a program in vb.net 2013 . and it's running fine on my computer windows 7

when i did setup for program on the other computer . everything works fine except

when i try to open a file to select a picture .once i click open button  the program freezes for a minute then it throws exception :

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:    BEX
  Application Name::    BaldEagle.exe
  Application Version:    1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    55b3c11d
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_0a9e
  Fault Module Version:    0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:    00000000
  Exception Offset:    c176c13f
  Exception Code:    c0000005
  Exception Data:    00000008
  OS Version:    6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1    0a9e
  Additional Information 2    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
 Additional Information 3    0a9e
  Additional Information 4    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Privacy policy on the internet:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0401

The code of opening a file to select a picture :

```
 Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.Filter = "Text Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG(*.png)|*.png|gif(*.gif)|*.gif|JPEG(*.jpeg)|*.jpeg"
    ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(ofd.FileName)
        If bmp.Width.ToString = "300" And bmp.Height.ToString = "300" Then
            ' MsgBox("Cool")

        Else
            MsgBox("must be 300×300")
            Exit Sub
        End If



        If Application.StartupPath & "\set\logo.png" = ofd.FileName Then
            MsgBox("this is actually your ccurrent logo", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If MsgBox("do you want to change logo ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Application.StartupPath & "\set\logo.png") = True Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath & "\set\logo.png")
            End If
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(ofd.FileName, Application.StartupPath & "\set\logo.png")
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: there is an actual exception message, aside from the details portion.  If I were to guess, my first would be that your app does not have permission to delete or copy to the StartupPath  which could be `Program Files`.  Also, rather than yelling at the user, you could change the size of the bitmap and *make* it 300x300. you also have lots of stuff not being disposed.

Comment: @Plutonix thank you . can you tell me what should i do if i wanted my program to delete or copy to startup . because the program is running as administrator . is there also any way other run it as administrator

Answer (score 1):

The StackHash error occurs when DEP (Data Execution Prevention) is invoked and has an issue with the application you’re trying to run. Note: I have tried your code and it work's just fine on my machine.

Please see if these steps help to fix the issue...

1. Click on the Start menu and then go to the Control Panel.
2. Click on System Maintenance and then System.
3. Choose Advanced System Settings.
4. Under System Properties, select Settings from the Performance section at the top.
5. Click on the Data Execution Prevention tab.
6. Select “Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select”.
7. Find the executable file for the application that triggered the error.
8. Select the application causing the error and click Open to add it to your DEP Exceptions list.
9. Click OK to save your new settings.

More on this issue **[here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3932e3eb-c034-4eb7-aa06-4a0a8e6ea493/fault-module-namestackhash0a9e)**.

Comment: a message box appears : " Cannot disable DEP for this application "

what should i do ?

Comment: Open command prompt as an administrator and run this: **bcdedit.exe /set nx AlwaysOff**

Comment: i have disabled it successfully . but the problem is still there . i can't use openfiledialog . But it works just fine on my laptop .

Comment: I did system restore to point . it helped and solved the problem . thanks

Comment: I literally was baffled by this issue. Mine was not vb.net related but vb6 related, which I assume doesn't matter. When I built my program on my machine and distributed it, it would get the BEX error. I then built it on another machine, distributed, and then it worked fine. #whatintarnation